# debian 10.3 crontab problem

Tags: debian, cron

i use debian 10.3 xfce and i use this command :

```
crontab -e
```

and put this line to the end of file :

```
*/1 * * * * xdg-open /home/myusername/1.txt
```

and exit and this message appears:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

but nothing happend after that and when i check the cron service with this command :

```
sudo cron service status
```

it said :

```
cron: can't lock /var/run/crond.pid, otherpid may be 4535: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

then i use this command :

```
/etc/init.d/cron restart
[ ok ] Restarting cron (via systemctl): cron.service.
```

but after that the output of "sudo cron service status" is the same as before and nothing happend.
what is the problem ?

Comment: Probably the command should be `sudo service cron status` (or `systemctl status cron.service` to use the `systemd` interface directly). However you may find that `xdg-open` commands fail when run from inside cron, since they know nothing about desktop sessions.

Comment: i uesed a simple script that hold xdg-open /path to txt file and put the path of my script to the crontab but nothing happend

Comment: Using a script won't help. xdg-open still can't know you have an X11 server started (and you could even have several of them!). In a shell, check `echo $DISPLAY`. It's probably ":0". Then try to pass that to xdg-open: `DISPLAY=:0 xdg-open yourtextfile.txt`.

Comment: i use your advice and i do another job (add my username to crontab group) and it worked . thanks

Answer (score 0):

cron is running using systemd so `sudo cron service status` wont return anything useful.
But you should be able to verify that cron is running bye doing `systemctl status cron`

Comment: the output of "systemctl status cron.service" is :  cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: ena
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-30 08:31:56 EDT; 1h 12min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 4535 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 2336)
   Memory: 11.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─4535 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Comment: It looks like cron is running fine. But like steeldriver said running gui apps from cron isn't exactly desirable.
If you intention is  is to verify cron is actually running jobs you could do something simple like
`* * * * * touch ~/itWorks`

Comment: i added my username to crontab group and after a while it worked